# How many people live in Luna?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, the-moon-is-a-harsh-mistress

At the time of the events told in Robert Heinlein's *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* (not counting the epilogue), approximately how many people live in Luna?

I seem to remember that the number was mentioned somewhere in the book, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the first installment in [*If*, December 1965](https://archive.org/stream/1965-12_IF#mode/2up), p. 22, column 2:

> Wyoh smiled. “Yes, we could throw rocks. But the solution is so simple that you all know it. Here in Luna we’re rich. **Three million hardworking, smart, skilled people,** enough water, plenty of everything, endless power, endless cubic. *But* 
>   . . . what we *don't* have is a free market. *We must get rid of the Authority!*"

Comment: Chapter 2 of the novel.

Answer (score 5):

### 3000000

Found it while researching for another question.  Chapter 11:

> Despite “throwing rocks,” Mike knew, we all knew, that mighty terra with eleven billion people and endless resources could not be defeated by **three million** who had nothing, […]